# how to get rows with count of occurence (Frequency) in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My Database Table is having this type of data

Table Name : Logs

```
ID  ALBUMID GENREID
1   1005    5
1   1008    5
1   1006    4
1   1005    5
1   1007    5
1   1007    4
1   1008    5
1   1008    5
1   1005    5
1   1005    4
1   1005    5
```

and the result I am expecting is for get  - Top 2 Album id with frequency count for GenreId 5 which have maximum frequency..

Result :

```
AlbumId Frequency
1005      4
1008      3
```

here is SQL Fiddle Link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aaa9e/13

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try:

```
select top 2 ALBUMID, COUNT(*) Frequency
from tbl
where GENREID=5
group by ALBUMID 
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Thanks , Working as expected